# System program problem detected... but what?

Tags: system, mate

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu MATE 18.04 and I am just getting everything situated the way I want it, programs installed and updated but every time I restart my computer, I get this error that says "system program problem detected" and asks if I'd like to report it. But that is all. It mentions nothing about fixing it or what the problem is, so is there a way I can manually find out what the issue is so I can take the right steps in fixing it? Maybe a terminal command? I'm fairly new to Linux so I'm not sure if this is an easy solution or not. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

not sure if the entire output is needed but i enclosed it just to be sure but im pretty sure the only line you need is:

```
[    1.763161] [drm:construct [amdgpu]] *ERROR* construct: Invalid Connector ObjectID from Adapter Service for connector index:2! type 0 expected 3
```

contents of entire output from `dmesg` are [here on the Ubuntu Pastebin site](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BnqKWQWVmm/) (too many characters to fit here)

Comment: NOTE: Your `dmesg` output would make it impossible to add additional data to your question, so I snipped it and put it into a Pastebin and added the link in. 
 That way, it's able to be read and used but won't overload the site and your ability to add more data.  When you see "System Problem Detected" does it give yuo the opportunity to open a report or see more details?  Does `ls -l /var/crash` have any output, and if so what is it?

Comment: @K7AAY They did so, but pasted it into their question, I've adjusted it to be in a pastebin and edited the link in.  (Because I did a favor)

Comment: thank you @thomas, not familiar with how to do all of that. but here is the output from your request:
total 40392
-rw-r----- 1 root whoopsie 41358974 Oct 20 07:45 _usr_sbin_aptd.0.crash
and no, the message that pops up only allows me to "report the problem" or "cancel"

Comment: Use "Report the Problem" it'll send the crash report into the system for it to be reviewed.  My guess is since you don't have more than one crash report there, it's a temporary one.  You can do `sudo rm /var/crash/_usr_sbin_aptd.0.crash` to remove the crash file.  After you do that, restart the system, if the same popup comes up again then we know something is crashing (but dmesg might not be providing us enough data).

Comment: I would still hit "Report the Problem" though before removing it.

Comment: ok so i ran that code in the terminal, restarted and it didn't come back, that means im good now?!

Comment: something caused aptdaemon to crash but there's no way to determine why from the crash file unless you're very well versed in how to read them (basically, a dev who understands how it's structured).  As long as it doesn't return again, you should be fine - if it starts showing up again then something else crashed and hasn't been handled or reported.

Comment: ok sounds good, i really appreciate the help